# Can't figure out how to load jsonData into an NSDictionary using NSURLSession in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, nsurlsession

Good day to you all. First i would like to inform you that i am very new at programming in general. Therefore, i would like to apologise upfront, if i'm not making any sense.  I've done a bootcamp for iOS Swift but that didn't include Rest or parsing JSON. I am now trying to teach myself doing all tutorials i can find. I know there's Alamofire which makes it much easier, but i would like to learn how to do it using NSURLSession first. I've found a tutorial which was written in an older version of Swift and now i've been stuck for days. I've tried all the options that i could find here and on Google. But i still can't understand what i'm doing wrong. This is my code; and underneath it i've described where i think the problem occurs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FlickrHelper: NSObject {

class func UrlForSearchString(searchString: String) -> String {
    let apiKey:String = "733e5b6f446812afdec3c021454dd9bb"
    let search:String = searchString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=\(apiKey)&text=\(search)&per_page=20&format=json&njsoncallback=1"

}
class func UrlForFlickrPhoto(photo:FlickrPhoto, size:String) -> String {
    var _size = size
    if _size.isEmpty {
        _size = "m"
    }
    return "http://farm.\(photo.farm).staticflickr.com/\(photo.photoID)_\(photo.secret)_\(_size).jpg"
}

func searchFlickrForString(searchStr:String, completion:(searchString:String!, flickrPhotos:NSMutableArray!, error:NSError!) -> ()) {

    let searchUrl:String = FlickrHelper.UrlForSearchString(searchStr)
    let queue:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

    dispatch_async(queue, {

        var error:NSError?

        let searchResultString:String! = try! String(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: searchUrl)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        if error != nil {
            completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: nil, error: error)
        } else {
            // Parse json response.

            let jsonData:NSData! = searchResultString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

            let resultDict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject] as NSDictionary

            let status:String = resultDict?.objectForKey("stat") as! String

            if status == "fail" {
                let stError:NSError? = NSError(domain: "FlickrSearch", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey:(resultDict?.objectForKey("message"))!])

                completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: nil, error: stError)
            } else {
                let resultArray:NSArray = (resultDict?.objectForKey("photos")?.objectForKey("photo"))! as! NSArray

                let flickrPhotos:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

                for photoObject in resultArray {
                    let photoDict:NSDictionary = photoObject as! NSDictionary

                    var flickrPhoto:FlickrPhoto = FlickrPhoto()
                    flickrPhoto.farm = photoDict.objectForKey("farm") as! Int
                    flickrPhoto.server = photoDict.objectForKey("server") as! String
                    flickrPhoto.secret = photoDict.objectForKey("secret") as! String
                    flickrPhoto.photoID = photoDict.objectForKey("id") as! String

                    let searchURL:String = FlickrHelper.UrlForFlickrPhoto(flickrPhoto, size: "m")
                    do {
                    let imageData:NSData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: searchURL)!, options: NSDataReadingOptions())

                        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data:imageData)!

                        flickrPhoto.thumbnail = image

                        flickrPhotos.addObject(flickrPhoto)

                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }

                    completion(searchString: searchStr, flickrPhotos: flickrPhotos, error: nil)

                }
            }
        }
    })
  }
}
```

I receive jsonData but it's not assigning it to my resultDict. My resultDict is nil. The line where my project crashes is this one:

```
 let status:String = resultDict?.objectForKey("stat") as! String
```

But i'm guessing the problem is in this line:

```
let resultDict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject] as NSDictionary
```

Comment: Avoid using forced unwrapping or implicitly unwrapped optionals wherever possible. Basically any use of the `!` operator. You need to actually check if a cast is successful or you could set yourself up for a runtime crash somewhere down the line. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I am actually trying to get it work first and after that i will clean it up using if let and try,do,catch. That would be a next exercise for me :-).

Comment: I understand that you would like to do this yourself to learn. But I would recommend using SwiftlyJson for controlling the JSON deserialization once you have tried this. This cuts out a lot of the optional chaining you will end up having to do. This still uses what you have for network calls etc, it just makes the parsing of the JSON more pleasant. You can find it here: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @totiG: Thanks, you're right. It's what most people are using now with Alamofire. I am looking forward to using it.

Comment: `as! [String:AnyObject] as NSDictionary` Why would you do that? If I may suggest a first step to debugging your code: remove every useless operation, analyze every line and ask yourself what it does and why. Make things simpler and safer: use `if let` instead of `!`, don't cast the same object twice, etc.

Comment: @Eric D, that was a desperation try    as! Dictionary was my default. I went over it over and over again. Everything seems correct, when i debug, i have my jsonData as NSData but i can't get it in my resulDict.

Comment: Anyone else that might have an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what other idea you would need, as you already have the solution: clean your code. Remove the useless code. Remove the multiple casts. Replace every force-unwrap with `if let` and `else` branches to catch the errors. Don't mix `try!` and `try?` if you don't know why you're using both, just use the normal `try` with error handling. *Debug.*

Comment: @ Eric D.: Will try that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Instead of passing in an empty array to NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData, use the allow with fragment type, like so:

```
let resultDict = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
```

That might solve the problem. Otherwise try some of the other options.

---

Another approach could be this.

```
            let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json!, options: .AllowFragments)
            print("=====")
            if let item = json.objectForKey("prices") as! NSArray? {
                self.uberPriceField.text = item[0].objectForKey("estimate") as? String
            }
```

I have used this in my own code, because the JSON that got returned was actually just an array at the top level. Maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that was also something that i've already tried :-(.

Comment: Thanks, even though i'm very sure my JSON is a Dictionary (it starts with { ) i did try your suggestion. Unfortunately it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code which i am using in my proj , refer the same and let me know if still issue persists:-

```
 let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "(Ur URL)/get_SearchList.php?cth=\(cth),\(kwValue)")!
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if (statusCode == 200) {

                do{

                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)



                    if let products = json["product"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        for product in products {

                                if let cth = product["cth"] as? String {


                                    if let name = product["productname"] as? String {
                                        self.cthArray.append(cth);
                                        self.prodArray.append(name);


                                    }

                                }


                        }//for loop
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            })
                        })

                    }// if loop

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                }

            }
            else
            {
                // No internet connection
                // Alert view controller
                // Alert action style default


            }

        }

        task.resume()
```